# fopen() fails to create a file on linux

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to create a file through `fopen()` as below :

```
<?php 
  $handle = fopen('name.txt', 'w') or die('Can\'t create file');
  fwrite($handle, 'Hamed'."\n");
  fwrite($handle, 'Kamrava'."\n");
  echo 'File was created successfully';
?>
```

But doesn't create that file and get me:

`Can't create file`

**P.S :**

I'm using LAMP server on Linux/Ubuntu.

I've tried below command before creating that file:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/public_html/
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that `~/public_html/` is current working directory? Have you tried an absolute filename?

Comment: @AlexShesterov Yes i'm sure about working dir. What's your mean about absolute file name?

Comment: Absolute filename is `/path/and/file.name`. But if current working dir is set to `~/public_html/` then using absolute filename won't help. You've got an answer meanwhile :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PHP script is executed as the user configured for the Apache web server. In order to create files, this user has to have write permission to the directory in which you want to create the file. There are two ways to do this:

You can give the write permission to the directory for all users, which will include whatever is configured for Apache (good enough for a development machine):

```
chmod o+w ~/public_html/directory_where_you_want_to_write
```

*Or* you can pass the ownership of the directory to the Apache user. This will mean that *you* with your regular user account won't be able create or delete files in this directory though, unless you also do the above. Assuming Apache runs with the `www-data` user account, like it does by default on Ubuntu, you would do:

```
sudo chown www-data ~/public_html/directory_where_you_want_to_write
```

(And the directory doesn't have to be under `public_html`, I'm just using it as an example since that seems to be where your files are.)

Comment: You can put your user into the appropriate group (`www`?) and then grant write access to the group.

Answer (score 0):

the folder has to be owned by apache user so:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/public_html/
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of the folder(in which you are trying to create) to all permission

```
sudo chmod 777
```

Comment: What is a `ur tring`?