# Create a file from content of ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to have a php script that creates a file from the content of an ajax post. File to be called report.txt

I have this php script located at /var/www/copypaste.test/public_html/index.php

```
<?php

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 $report = $_POST['report'];
 echo $report;

 $report_file = fopen("report.txt", "w");
 fwrite($report_file, $report);
?>
```

and the i have a simple ajax post for now with some test text

```
 var text = 'test string';

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('report', text);

 var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://copypaste.test',
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'text',
  processData: false, 
  contentType: false,
    success: function(){ 
      console.log('success'); 
    },
    error: function() {
     console.log('error'); 
    } 
  });
 }
```

The ajax post is successful as i get `test string` in the response and this in my console

```
 readyState 4
 responseText "\ntest string"
 status  200
 statusText "OK"
```

when i then go to `http://copypaste.test` I don’t see the text or the creation of a file when going into the directory?

Could anyone point me in the right direction please

Thanks

Comment: Is the file actually created?

Comment: Failing to open and write to the file will not lead to a fatal error but just a warning. You should enable error display and add error handling to your file-writing calls.

Comment: No file created, could you show me an example of error handling please.. I take it you mean on the php side?

Comment: you can't open same url in browser and expect to see data that was sent via ajax.

Comment: The Ajax call is done in a separate tab, for now creation of the file would suffice

Comment: @Richlewis Try this and see what you get: `$report_file = fopen("report.txt", "w") or die("Failed to create file");`

Comment: @caeth I get Failed to create file when i open copypaste.test

Comment: Probably something with apache permissions then, take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776004/fopen-fails-to-create-a-file-on-linux

Comment: yup permissions it was, thanks for the help, make that an answer if you like and then ill accept

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you never call fclose("report.txt") to close the file after writing.  This can cause problems.

You can you use this function call to handle the opening, writing, and closing of a file.

```
  file_put_contents("report.txt",$report);
```

You might try replacing the "report.txt" in the function call above just in case the file is still open in memory and you are not able to access it.